# Mobile website display isn't working correctly

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm currently developing my website, and everything is working as far as I know, except for the mobile page. Below are two screenshots of my mobile page:

[image: Adobe dreamweaver mobile preview]
[image: Real Website preview]

The first one displays the adobe dreamweaver preview on my phone. This is how it should look.
The second one displays the website that's online at the moment.
It's the same website as the desktop version.

The files are both the same, but display another result.
Can someone help me with this problem?

What I already did:
Validated my HTML code.
Synched it to the FTP server to be sure I didn't mess up files.
Checked the CSS and my phone width

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a responsive page? All media queries set up? Are you using any framework? If its not loading you mobile page, than CSS is not set up correctly. Little more details would help...

Comment: The website is responsive, as seen in the screenshots (the Dreamweaver preview shows the correct website). 
All media queries are set up, and I don't use any frameworks.
The CSS is set up correctly, otherwise it wouldn't load the correct page at first, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what your problem is?

It seems correct from the screen. Put also a bit of code.

From this point of view I can only ask you if you put the various links to `Bootstrap`.